# How to refresh a view calling RedirectToAction?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

How can I refresh a view within a controller method calling redirect (or equivalent)?

**View (Index.cshtml):**

```
@model ViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.First)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Last)

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Junk)

// call is invoked to PerformMagic as such:

onComplete: function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) 
{
   $.ajax(
   { url: '@Url.Action("PerformMagic","Home")',
       data: { first: $("#fname").val() },
      })
   }
```

**Junk.cshtml (Editor Template)**

```
 @model Models.Junk

 <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID)
</div>
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
// Called from jquery client
public string PerformMagic(string Id)
{
    ViewModel model = dbContext.GetPersistedView();
    model.Junk.Add(new junk);

    // I need to update my view here but this doesn't update the view (model updates fine)....
    // ...after a refresh on the browser of course the new junk in the model is displayed.
    return RedirectToAction("Index", model);  
}
```

Comment: _"this doesn't work"_ can you say what doesn't work? what happens? do you reach this Action with an `ajax` request???

Comment: Yessss. I was right... See my answer below. My crystal ball works like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are making an `ajax` request.

You can't redirect an `ajax` request! what you should do is return Json values of the model and in the client side update the page:

```
public string PerformMagic(string Id)
{
    ViewModel model = dbContext.GetPersistedView();
    model.Junk.Add(new junk);

    return Json(model);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("PerformMagic","Home")',
        data: {
            first: $("#fname").val()
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#First').val(response.First);
            $('#Last').val(response.Last);
            $('#Junk').val(response.Junk);...
        }
    })
}​
```

Comment: Thx, I'm fairly new to client side stuff.  How could I update my view with the new junk client side?  The junk get's displayed in a bunch of divs so not sure how I would pass in the new junk to get displayed?  I'm using @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Junk).

Comment: Cool! So, for Junk will it display correctly?  new Junk{id = 2, name ="firstone"}.  These are displayed in their own editor template that displays the id and name of each junk object in the junk collection.

Comment: @JaJ. If `Junk` is not a "simple object" (`int\string\long\DateTime`etc') but a complexed object, you have to update each element separately. How? it depends on the template. check the DOM structure to know what selector you need get each element of junk, and check what is the response structure as well. Good Luck!

Comment: @JaJ. I saw your update. try this: `$('#ID').val(response.Junk.ID)` not sure about the "case" of Junk, maybe it should be lowercase, You didn't paste it's code. how is that?